# Converting JSON object to Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am unfamiliar with how to convert JSON objects to DataFrames. I am hoping to get some ideas of more efficient ways to convert JSON objects to DataFrames.

When I loop through 2 rows of my `input_df`, I will get 2 JSON objects when I print `suggestion_string` as follows:

[image]

My expected output would be a data frame as follows:

| suggestion1 | reason1 | suggestion2 | reason2 | suggestion3 | reason3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| free text | free text | free text | free text | free text | free text |
| free text | free text | free text | free text | free text | free text |

I had attempted with the codes as follows, and it worked; but I am hoping to get some ideas for more efficient ways to do the conversion.

```py
suggestion_list = []

for i in range(len(input_df)):

    description = input_df.loc[i, 'description']
    
    query = fr"""
    sample text ... {description}?
    """
    
    suggestion_string = return_json_object(query)
    string = suggestion_string.replace("`",'')
    string = string.replace('json', '')
    str_list = string.split('\n')
    dict_str = ''.join(str_list)
    output_dict = json.loads(dict_str)
    suggestion_list.append(output_dict)

lists_of_dicts = []
for dict in suggestion_list:
    list_of_dicts.append(dict['suggestions'])

flat_data = []
for sublist in list_of_dicts:
    row_data = {}
    for i, item in enumerate(sublist):
        row_data[f'suggestion{i+1}'] = item['suggestion']
        row_data[f'reason{i+1}'] = item['reason']
    flat_data.append(row_data)

suggestion_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_data)
```

Comment: Can you post your json directly instead of a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created dummy suggestion strings - but you can continue your for loop by modifying the following code and incorporating your `input_df` logic. I have hardcoded the suggestions strings for simplicity.

Code:

````py
import pandas as pd
import json

suggestion_string_1 = '''
```
json
{
    "suggestions": [
        {"suggestion": "free text", "reason": "free text"},
        {"suggestion": "free text", "reason": "free text"},
        {"suggestion": "free text", "reason": "free text"}
    ]
}
```
'''

suggestion_string_2 = '''
```
json
{
    "suggestions": [
        {"suggestion": "free text", "reason": "free text"},
        {"suggestion": "free text", "reason": "free text"},
        {"suggestion": "free text", "reason": "free text"}
    ]
}
```
'''

suggestion_list = []
input_df = [suggestion_string_1, suggestion_string_2]

for i in range(len(input_df)):
    # description = input_df.loc[i, 'description']
    #
    # query = fr"""
    # sample text ... {description}?
    # """
    #
    # suggestion_string = return_json_object(query)

    # I have hard-coded the suggestion_string for brevity - 
    # Assuming you are getting the same strings that I have 
    # hard-coded as per the screenshot shared by you.
    suggestion_string = input_df[i] # So, you can just replace this line with your logic for getting the suggestion string.
    suggestions = json.loads(
        suggestion_string[suggestion_string.find('{'):suggestion_string.rfind('}') + 1]
    )['suggestions']
    suggestion_list.append(suggestions)

suggestion_df = pd.DataFrame()

for idx, suggestions in enumerate(suggestion_list):
    for i, suggestion in enumerate(suggestions):
        suggestion_df.loc[idx, f'suggestion{i+1}'] = suggestion['suggestion']
        suggestion_df.loc[idx, f'reason{i+1}'] = suggestion['reason']
        
print(suggestion_df)
````

Output:

| suggestion1 | reason1 | suggestion2 | reason2 | suggestion3 | reason3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| free text | free text | free text | free text | free text | free text |
| free text | free text | free text | free text | free text | free text |

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function and a sample json file to test it on. This function is applicable to any type of json, with or without nested fields.

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "john@example.com",
        "location": {
            "city": "New York",
            "country": "USA"
        },
        "skills": ["Python", "Data Analysis"]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "email": "jane@example.com",
        "location": {
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "country": "USA"
        },
        "skills": ["JavaScript", "React"]
    }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

Apllying it

```
flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

retunrs

```
   index  id      name             email  location.city location.country  \
0      0   1  John Doe  john@example.com       New York              USA   
0      0   1  John Doe  john@example.com       New York              USA   
1      1   2  Jane Doe  jane@example.com  San Francisco              USA   
1      1   2  Jane Doe  jane@example.com  San Francisco              USA   

          skills  
0         Python  
0  Data Analysis  
1     JavaScript  
1          React
```